# googlesigninbutton doesnt react to click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

My google sign in button doesnt work and I dont know why.
I made an OnClickListener wich should work but the Google Signin Button never responds.

Here, my code:

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "LoginProcess";
    Intent mapIntent;
    SignInButton gsignInButton;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View rootView;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
        mapIntent = new Intent(TabbedActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Toast.makeText(TabbedActivity.this, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Toast.makeText(TabbedActivity.this, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        };

        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcomescreenlogin,  null);
        gsignInButton = (SignInButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        gsignInButton.setOnClickListener(onClick);


        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    }

    View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    signIn();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }

    }

    public void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(TabbedActivity.this, "Signup Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(TabbedActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

And here my Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/welcomegradientlogin">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Sign in to Google"
    android:id="@+id/Welcome"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFFF"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Welcome"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem may have to do something with the fact that the class extends "Appcompatactivity" or just that the other methods to execute the signin process arent written correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
please add this line in Button

android:onClick="onClick"

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Welcome"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    />
```